# line numbering including blank (empty lines)

Tags: formatting, line-numbering

I have a latex document and I would like to include line numbers in it, the tricky part is that I need to count the blank (empty) lines too (emulating what MSWord does :(.
I know I could use the package lineno but it doesn't seem to have an option for counting blank lines.

any ideas? thanks

Comment: This is because the blank lines aren't really blank lines - they are vertical gaps of varying length. From the user input end, if you want a blank line, insert `\par\mbox{}\par`, but that's kinda tedious...

Comment: You want to emulate MSWord? OMG. Throw a cup of coffee on your computer, that should do it.

Comment: hahaha great comment!!!
 I wish I didn't have to do it, believe me: I DO NOT LIKE Word! but I need this for work :( it is definitely not my choice...

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a blank line that will be marked using a macro

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno,lipsum}

\newcommand{\markblankline}{\par\mbox{}\par}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\lipsum[1]

\markblankline

\lipsum[2]

\markblankline

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Using such explicit blank-line-numbering seems extreme. However, your document may contain a whole host of formatting options that might not interact well with [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) as it stands.

If your document contains straight-forward text, perhaps the following may be of use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno,lipsum,everyhook}

\newcommand{\markblankline}{\par\mbox{}\par}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\lipsum[1]

\PushPreHook{par}{\hspace*{-\parindent}\makebox[\linewidth]{}\\\hspace*{\parindent}}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

The above code provides the same output by appending a blank line with every issue of `\par` thanks to the [`everyhook` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyhook).